# Testing if a checkbox is checked with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-selectors

If the checkbox is checked, then I only need to get the value as 1; otherwise, I need to get it as 0.  How do I do this using jQuery?

`$("#ans").val()` will always give me one right in this case:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ans" value="1" />
```

Comment: .val() is to get the value attribute, not the check status. The value attribute can be anything, it doesn't need to be boolean.

Comment: if you're still around, you may want to update the accepted answer for modern software... a lot of people still see this question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether a checkbox is checked in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-to-check-whether-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1013, accepted):

Use `.is(':checked')` to determine whether or not it's checked, and then set your value accordingly.

[More information here.](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-check-if-checkbox-is-checked.html)

Comment: In addition, when you do $("#id").is("checked") in a if clause you'll get true or false, not on/off,  by return and you can send it to your back-end script and do whatever you want.

Comment: Probably this doesn't matter nowadays: ReSharper (I guess) outputs a warning "**The pseudo-class 'checked' is not compatible with Internet Explorer 8.0**".

Answer (score 213):

```
$("#ans").attr('checked')
```

will tell you if it's checked.  You can also use a second parameter true/false to check/uncheck the checkbox.

```
$("#ans").attr('checked', true);
```

Per comment, use `prop` instead of `attr` when available. E.g:

```
$("#ans").prop('checked')
```

Answer (score 90):

Just use `$(selector).is(':checked')`

It returns a boolean value.

Answer (score 57):

```
// use ternary operators
$("#ans").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: @Loic to set his value using the terse ternary syntax, eg: : a = ischecked ? 1 : 0

Answer (score 24):

[@StefanBrinkmann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16041108/584676) is excellent, but incomplete for beginners (omits the variable assignment). Just to clarify:

```
// this structure is called a ternary operator
var cbAns = ( $("#ans").is(':checked') ) ? 1 : 0;
```

It works like this:

```
 var myVar = ( if test goes here ) ? 'ans if yes' : 'ans if no' ;
```

Example:

```
var myMath = ( 1 > 2 ) ? 'yes' : 'no' ;
alert( myMath );
```

Alerts 'no'

Answer (score 18):

You can try this:

```
$('#studentTypeCheck').is(":checked");
```

Answer (score 15):

I've found the same problem before,
hope this solution can help you.
first, add a custom attribute to your checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ans" value="1" data-unchecked="0" />
```

write a jQuery extension to get value:

```
$.fn.realVal = function(){
    var $obj = $(this);
    var val = $obj.val();
    var type = $obj.attr('type');
    if (type && type==='checkbox') {
        var un_val = $obj.attr('data-unchecked');
        if (typeof un_val==='undefined') un_val = '';
        return $obj.prop('checked') ? val : un_val;
    } else {
        return val;
    }
};
```

use code to get check-box value:

```
$('#ans').realVal();
```

you can test [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7wGaP/)

Comment: ...because jQuery is known as "the write more do less" library

Comment: long story you have gone to far JQUERY want developer to write less and do extra more. simple problem deserve simple solution

Comment: yes, agreed, write less, do more. you write the extension once, and for the rest of time, you only call the API $(someradio).realVal(), you don't need write a extension many times.

Comment: You didn't even need to write the extension once, nevermind 'many times'! O.o

Answer (score 8):

```
$('input:checkbox:checked').val();        // get the value from a checked checkbox
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ans" value="1" />
```

Jquery  : 
  `var test= $("#ans").is(':checked')`
and it return true or false.

In your function:

```
$test =($request->get ( 'test' )== "true")? '1' : '0';
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use:

```
$("#ans:checked").length == 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
$("#ans option:selected").val()
```

Comment: if it's not selected, then the first part wouldn't return anything, right?

Comment: @Senthil, OP is not asking to get the value of a selected checkbox, rather `return` `1` if it is selected

Answer (score 4):

```
function chkb(bool){
if(bool)
return 1;
return 0;
}

var statusNum=chkb($("#ans").is(':checked'));
```

statusNum will equal 1 if the checkbox is checked, and 0 if it is not.

EDIT: You could add the DOM to the function as well.

```
function chkb(el){
if(el.is(':checked'))
return 1;
return 0;
}

var statusNum=chkb($("#ans"));
```

Answer (score 4):

I've came through a case recently where I've needed check value of checkbox when user clicked on button. The only proper way to do so is to use `prop()` attribute.

```
var ansValue = $("#ans").prop('checked') ? $("#ans").val() : 0;
```

this worked in my case maybe someone will need it.

When I've tried `.attr(':checked')` it returned `checked` but I wanted boolean value and `.val()` returned value of attribute `value`.

Answer (score 4):

There are Several options are there like....

```
 1. $("#ans").is(':checked') 
 2. $("#ans:checked")
 3. $('input:checkbox:checked');
```

If all these option return true then you can set value accourdingly.

Comment: The first one should be (':checked'), doesn't work otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('input:checkbox:checked').click(function(){
    var val=(this).val(); // it will get value from checked checkbox;
})
```

Here flag is true if checked otherwise false

```
var flag=$('#ans').attr('checked');
```

Again this will make cheked

```
$('#ans').attr('checked',true);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $("#id").prop('checked') === true ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get value (true/false) by these two method

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked");
$("input[type='checkbox']").is(":checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want integer value of checked or not, try:

```
$("#ans:checked").length
```

Answer (score 0):

First check the value is checked

```
$("#ans").find("checkbox").each(function(){
    if ($(this).prop('checked')==true){ 
    var id = $(this).val()
    }
});
```

Else set the **0** value

Answer (score 0):

You can perform it, this way:

```
$('input[id=ans]').is(':checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following worked for me, with a mix of one of the answers, but with if statement.

```
$('#checkbox').on('change', function () {
 let checkbox_true;
  checkbox_true = $('#checkbox').prop("checked") ? 1 : 0 ;
   if (checkbox_true === 1) {
     alert('Yes');
   } else {
     alert('no');
   }
})
```