# How can I check if a checkbox is checked on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to trigger some code when I click a checkbox based on if a checkbox is checked or not. 
But for some reason, `.is(':checked')` is always triggered.

This is my code.

```
  jQuery('#selectlist input[type=checkbox]').live('click',function(){
    var select_id = jQuery(this).attr('id');

    if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
      alert('You have unchecked the checkbox');
      // Remove some data from variable
    } else {
      alert('You have checked the checkbox');
      //Add data to variable
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE**
I've added an example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HgQUS/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `change` instead of `click`

Comment: It doesn't matter is I use `change` or `click`, the result is still the same. See my example here> http://jsfiddle.net/HgQUS/

Comment: @Steven -- it works fine, you just had your if statement backwards: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/HgQUS/4/

Comment: How can `if(jQuery(this).is(':checked'))` be backwards? Doesn't this controll if a checkbox is checked?

Comment: Yes I get that. I just don't understand the logic behind the `if(jQuery(this).is(':checked'))`. To me this should check if the checkbox is checked. Or is my logic all wrong here?

Comment: Ok, never mind. @Aleks said what I was thinking, that when I click it, it _is_ set to checked :)

Comment: @Steven it does check if the checkbox **IS** checked. but you wrote `You have unchecked the checkbox` when it is **is** checked. which is wrong ^_^, it needs to be flipped (which is what i did in my fiddle :-))

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).val();
```

or

```
$(this).prop('checked'); # on jquery >= 1.6
```

You will be better at searching over SO:

- [Get checkbox value in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834350/jquery-checkbox-value)
- [How to retrieve checkboxes values in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786142/how-to-retrieve-checkboxes-values-in-jquery)
- [Testing if a checkbox is checked with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813219/jquery-checkbox-value)

Comment: Ah, the `propr` function. Forgot about that. But the result is still the same :( http://jsfiddle.net/HgQUS/2/ It's acting the oposit of what it's supposed to.

Comment: Check your code, you are triggering the opposite action... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
this.checked
```

Should tell you if the checkbox is checked or not although this is just javascript so you won't be able to call it on a 'jquery' element. For example -

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checky">
$("#checky")[0].checked
```

Answer (score 1):

If the input has the checked attribute, then it is obviously checked, it is removed if it is not checked.

```
if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
    // return true
}
else {
    // return false
}
```

However, you can adapt the above code to check if the attribute, if it is not removed and instead set to true/false, to the following:

```
if ($(this).attr("checked") == "true") {
    // return true
}
else {
    // return false
}
```

Additionally, I see you use jQuery as an operator for selectors, you can just use the dollar, `$`, symbol as that is a shortcut.

Comment: Tried that as well, doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/HgQUS/1/ Fore some reason it's acting the oposite of what it's supposed to do.

Comment: That is because you are using it the wrong way around xD - The statement you have written checks if the checkbox has been `changed`, as it sets the `checked` attribute, then runs the if statement. So what you want to do is just swap the content. http://jsfiddle.net/HgQUS/5/. :3

Comment: The html spec defines the content of the checked attribute as "checked", not "true": http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-INPUT

Comment: @Aleks - Ah yea. I was thinking that could be the case, but I was not sure.

Comment: @GaretJax, I did say that the first statement I wrote was for that, however I haves seen (mostly Internet Explorer related) cases of the `checked` attribute being used as a boolean.

Comment: @Steven. Hope it's all okay now ^_^

Answer (score 1):

I flipped-flopped the alerts, and it works for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('#selectlist input[type=checkbox]').live('click',function(){
    var select_id = jQuery(this).attr('id');

    if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert('You have checked the checkbox');
      // Remove some data from variable
    } else {
            alert('You have unchecked the checkbox');
      //Add data to variable
    }
  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "if" syntax is not correct.

```
jQuery('#selectlist_categories input[type=checkbox]').live('click',function(){
    var cat_id = jQuery(this).attr('id');

    // if the checkbox is not checked then alert "You have unchecked the checkbox"
    if(!jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
      alert('You have unchecked the checkbox');
    } else {
      //else alert "You have checked the checkbox"
      alert('You have checked the checkbox');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're confused about why it says `unchecked` when you check it. There is nothing ***wrong*** with your code you can just switch the `unchecked` and `checked` with each other in the alerts like this:

```
$('#selectlist_categories input[type=checkbox]').on('change',function(){
     var cat_id = $(this).attr('id');
     let cat_idText = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").val();
    
     if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
       alert('You have checked the checkbox' + " " + `${cat_idText}`); 
     } else {
       alert('You have unchecked the checkbox'); 
     }
});
```

> PS: I have updated the script to work in **jQuery 3.5.1** the original with the [`live()`](https://api.jquery.com/live/) only works on **jQuery 1.7** since it was removed in **1.9** to instead use [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) and on **jQuery 3.5.1** you can use `$` instead of `jQuery` and the [`val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) function works on all versions  because it added in **jQuery 1.0**

*Or in a nice better fashion correct the if statement as **`RickyCheers`** said adding the `!` before `jQuery` or `$` which then the if statement will turn it into a **if jQuery Element is not checked***

```
$('#selectlist_categories input[type=checkbox]').on('click',function(){
     var cat_id = $(this).attr('id');
    
     if(!jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
       alert('You have unchecked the checkbox');
     } else {
       alert('You have checked the checkbox');
     }
});
```