# How jQuery select a HTML input with its name and atttribute?

Tags: jquery, html, selector

I got a very common question that I want to get the value of a HTML input by jQuery selector with its name and specific attribute like checked. Following is my case:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="man" checked="checked" />
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="women"/>
```

I tried the following code:

```
var gener = $("name='gender':checked=checked").val();
```

But it didn't return a correct value. Hope somebody gives me help on it. Thanks.

Comment: poss dupe:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813219/jquery-checkbox-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813219/jquery-checkbox-value)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to type the element then the attribute, like this `$('element[attribute="value"]')`

```
$('input[name="gender"]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 4):

With the `:checked` selector, you don't need to provide a value, try this:

```
var gender = $('input[name="gender"]:checked').val();
```

More information in the [API docs](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[name="gender"]:checked').val();
```

Are you looking for something like that?