# JQuery MVC3 Inline Jquery Code

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

So, I have my MVC 3 view (Razor), with a form. Now it loads up the template which loads up all the scripts it uses, I put this at the top of the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#App_RunFromUSB').change(function () {
            alert($('#App_RunFromUSB').val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Which basically means that if the checkbox on the form is checked then alert the user of its value.

Simple, so why does it keep showing true in the alert box....

I put it in a fiddle and it does the same thing, [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dwb7N/)

Comment: for checkbox it will always show true as you have provided value to checkbox. you should check whether the checkbox is checked or not using jquery and then show appropriate message

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery checkbox value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813219/jquery-checkbox-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value is not changed because it's a checkbox. It's the property `checked` that gets changed, you can check it by using:

```
 $('#App_RunFromUSB').change(function () {
     alert($('#App_RunFromUSB').is(':checked'));
 });
```

See following DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Dwb7N/2/ to confirm. So the value alway remains the same.

Comment: how could you, on start up, check whether the checkbox is checked and change elements accordingly?

Comment: The answer to your new question has already been given, echoing out the answer it's: `$('#App_RunFromUSB').is(':checked');`

Comment: i know that bit... its the "on start up, change elements part"

Comment: What code do you have so far? Like I said it's the same thing so you could have: `$(document).ready(function(){ if ($('#App_RunFromUSB').is(':checked')) { then do some stuff here} });`. Comments have limited formatting so I hope you can understand that sample.

Comment: well because it is inline on a view I use $(function() {}); instead of $(document).ready(); which seems to work, thanks

Comment: in this case $el.prop('checked') be a more correct usage? performs better as well http://jsperf.com/prop-vs-ischecked/7

Answer (score 1):

If you are just wanting to alert the true/false depending on if the checkbox is checked or not, then update your code to;

```
alert($('#App_RunFromUSB').is(':checked'));
```

An example of your code with the change can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/Dwb7N/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#App_RunFromUSB').change(function () {
            alert($('#App_RunFromUSB').is(':checked'));
        });
    });
</script>
```