# get the second td value in dynamically generated datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

On my webpage, I have a button whose click dynamically generates a table. Each row of the table has a radio button. Now, I am trying to get the checked radio button nearest td value.. I mean the amount value..

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table table-bordered table-striped ">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div class="checker"><span><input type="checkbox" class="checkall"></span>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Agg Starts</th>
            <th>Agg Ends</th>
            <th>Next Renewal</th>
            <th>Term</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="checker"><span class=""><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="ads_Checkbox" value="2"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td><a class="show_hide1" href="" id="ah">1200000</a>
            </td>
            <td>15-01-2013</td>
            <td>31-12-2013</td>
            <td>01-01-2014</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="checker"><span class="checked"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="ads_Checkbox" value="65"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td><a href="" id="ah">200</a>
            </td>
            <td>19-11-2013</td>
            <td>19-11-2013</td>
            <td>24-11-2013</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: use a id for each and every radio buttons and reffer this [link][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813219/jquery-checkbox-value

Comment: hi if i click the check box, how i get the amount value (nearest td)

Comment: The question is not clear.I think you are trying to click a check box and get the value to a text box. is it ?

Comment: you meant, if you check first one it means 1200000 ?

Comment: ok. you have a seperate button. then you check a ckeck box and after click the button you need to get the value. is it ?

Comment: i have a common button , i dont need button in each row..

Comment: ok. you use a php code to generate the table. when generating table you can dinamically assign ids for every tds. then in check box id may c1, c2 , c3.... and tds with values may be vc1 , vc2 , vc3. vc1 is related to v1 accordingly. then write a code to the button(javascript) to get checked checkboxe's ids and you can get the values from vcx(x can be 1,2,3...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not clear. But, after reading the comments, I think this is what you need.

```
$(".checker input").change(function(){
    if(this.checked){
        var value = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(1)").find("a").text();
        alert(value);
    }

});
```

You can try it here.

http://jsfiddle.net/augusto1982/XPLx7/

Note: Using the `closest` method is a neat way of avoiding `parent().parent()...parent()` in your code.