# Retrieving the boolean state of a checkbox in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a checkbox.

```
<input id="new-consultation-open" type="checkbox" />
```

I'm trying to assign a boolean value to a variable that is equal to the state of the checkbox.

```
consultation.save({
    open: $("#new-consultation-open").val()
});
```

However, the value assigned to `open`is `'on'` regardless of whether the box is checked or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery checkbox value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813219/jquery-checkbox-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `val` method from jQuery will pick the `value` attribute from the checkbox, which is the text that will be submitted to the server once your form is sent in case it is checked. Most browsers set checkboxes value to `on` by default.

To check if it is checked in your client side code, you should use `.prop('checked')` instead.

```
consultation.save({
    open: $("#new-consultation-open").prop('checked')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

.val() is a truthy value at all times, because it isn't looking at the "checked" property of the input. Use this instead:

```
consultation.save({
    open: $('#new-consultation-open').attr('checked')
});
```

Comment: See Guilherme's answer. Use of the .prop() method is more current.