# Check if a checkbox is check in jQuery

Tags: jquery

So I would like to know after form submitting if a checkbox is checked or not.

I used this lines:

```
var isChecked = $('#USR_RememberMe').attr('checked') ? true : false;
alert(isChecked);
```

But `isChecked` is equals to `false` each times.

Could you please help me ?

Comment: `$('#USR_RememberMe').checked` should also work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing if a checkbox is checked with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813219/testing-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery)

Comment: Try [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). Also, note the "*Attributes vs. Properties*" section in the documentation for `.prop()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
$("#USR_RememberMe").is(":checked");
```

`:checked` is a pseudo class.